# Making request to localhost with Node client?

Tags: node.js

I have a very simple node server running on port 8080, and I'm trying to get an equally simple node client to hit this server.

Why does this code **not** work:

```
var http = require('https');

http.get('http://localhost:8080/headers', function(response) {
    console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers: ', response.headers);
    response.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

but this code **does** work?:

```
var http = require('http');
var client = http.createClient(8080, 'localhost');
var request = client.request('GET', '/headers');
request.end();
request.on("response", function (response) {
    console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers: ', response.headers);
    response.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

Comment: What version of node are you using? `http.createClient()` has been deprecated. Use `http.request()` https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you're loading the `https` module but trying to make a plain old HTTP request. You should use `http` instead.

```
var http = require('https');
```

should be:

```
var http = require('http');
```